# UITableView frame size strange behaviour

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I try to set frame size to my table view programmatically after viewDidLoad:

```
[_tableView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, topHeight, 
     [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width,
     [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height - topHeight)];
```

Default size is 200x200 with origin Y 100:

[image]

Scene hierarchy:

[image]

Implementation of UITableView shows when setFrame was called:

```
@implementation MainTableView

- (void)setFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    NSLog(@"setFrame: %f %f", frame.size.width, frame.size.height);
    [super setFrame:frame];
}

@end
```

All is fine but table's frame resizes to default when I press any cell without printing log messages from `setFrame`. Small explanation video: http://youtu.be/JUW_rHvCS2I

I don't understand why my table size becomes default (200x200) after cell click. Even if I try to set size inside `viewWillAppear` (after return from cell detail view) it doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't really tell why your tableView isn't resizing properly since you haven't provided much code to look around. Though I recommend setting some constraints or resizing rules for the tableView, probably something like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKtXQ.png (if not using Auto Layout)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpSZn.png (if using Auto Layout)

Now if you really need to make this work only trough code I suggest throwing up some NSLog's containing the tableView's frame width and height before and after setting it up.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Problem is I have dynamic created UI and I can't use constraints in this case. But your hint about Auto Layout led me to `viewDidLayoutSubviews` which solves my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try _tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO.